# Do we use else with unless statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There exists an opinion about `else` statement that we should not use it with `unless`?

Can anybody explain why this is so, or are we free to do whatever we like?

Comment: unless else is difficult to understand, and it can be easily replaced with an if else.

Comment: Else syntax exist in every language. and if it is not in javascript then there arise another question why it is not in javascript

Comment: Unless it's difficult for the reader to follow, it's fine. Else don't do it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You definitely **can** use `else` with `unless`. E.g.:

```
x=1
unless x>2
   puts "x is 2 or less"
else
  puts "x is greater than 2"
end
```

Will print "x is 2 or less".

But just because you **can** do something doesn't mean you **should**. More often than not, these constructs are convoluted to read, and you'd be better served to phrase your condition in a positive way, using a simple `if`:

```
x=1
if x<=2
   puts "x is 2 or less"
else
  puts "x is greater than 2"
end
```

Comment: how can i use this with select query if any id is nill like User.where(some condition).select(:name) unless id is.nil?

Comment: @gangothri if you have a different question I suggest you post it as its own question, not a comment here

Answer (score 23):

Yes, we can use `unless` with `else`. We are free to go wherever we like but some people have opinion that it's not a good habit to use `else` with `unless`. We need to avoid from this.

Unfortunately, unless statement supports only else construct not elsif or elseunless with in it.

```
unless true
  puts "one"
elsif true
  puts "two"
else
  puts "three"
end

SyntaxError: compile error
syntax error, unexpected kELSIF, expecting kEND
```

This may also be the reason that it restrict us.

Comment: For people who like the confusion that `unless` causes, I propose to add not only `elsif` but also `elsunless`.

Comment: Of course, since "elsif" is just short-hand for nesting another if inside the else, you could always write unless ... else { unless ... else { unless ... } }. Enjoy debugging it in 6 months time, though...

Comment: If this worked `puts "three"` would never be executed.

Comment: `puts "two"` also will never be executed. As written above the above code give error if you try to run it because the code contains syntax errors and the error is that we are not allowed to use elsif with unless.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing stopping anyone from using `unless - else`. It is perfectly valid. But the else part of unless-else is a **double negative**.

In some cases, `unless` is easy to comprehend. But when combined with an `else` statement, `if - else` is always **easier** to comprehend than `unless - else`. Imagine trying to understand the else part of an `unless - else` condition. It is a double negative and double negatives is just very not not wrong.

Also if there are many conditions with combinations of `&&` and `||` operators, `unless` becomes more difficult to comprehend

Comment: Both are easy to comprehend. At the end of the day its the developer's decision. Secondly rails developer frequently use unless so it is quite easy for them to understand it.

Comment: My be my example was bad. The person who wrote the code may understand it easily. But for another person looking at the code, might find it a little confusing. Moreover, we are talking about unless with else condition.

Comment: Rails developers may use it frequent and thus have no problems with `unless`, I - as non-rails developer - do. A kind of motto I once found is: ["Don’t obscure your (boolean) statement with unnecessary layers of negation".](https://schneide.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/dont-ever-not-avoid-negative-logic/)

Comment: agree that the level of comprehending difficulty depends on the programmer's preference.

Comment: I disagree.. In some cases, unless is easy to comprehend. But when combined with an else statement,  if - else is always EASIER to comprehend that unless - else...   Also if there are many conditions with combinations of && and || operators, unless becomes more difficult to comprehend.

Answer (score 7):

Ruby allows it, but *in English* "if ... else" (or "if ... otherwise") is a common construction whereas "unless ... else" is pretty much unheard of, to the point where many native speakers would reject it as incorrect.

This results in some confusion with `unless/else` in Ruby. People whose native language doesn't allow it just aren't used to following it. That's why there are many opinions against it. Since Ruby supports it you are of course free to do it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Yes we can use `unless` with `else` but it's not a good practice to write

```
unless foo
  # Foo
else
  #Bar
end
```

It's not better readable code. [Here](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-else-with-unless) is a Ruby coding style guide which most developers follow.

Answer (score 3):

Technically it is perfectly fine to use an `unless` with an `else`:

```
unless user.staff?
  # do foo
else
  # do bar
end
```

The only problem is that it is sometimes hard to read and to understand. Since code is way more often read than written, it makes much sense to focus on readablity and to write code that is easy to understand for other developers in the future.

Therefore you might want to change it to:

```
if !user.staff?
  # do bar
else
  # do foo
end
```

Or even better make remove the negation from the condition completely:

```
if user.customer?
  # do bar
else
  # do foo
end
```

`if true` is just easier to understand and simpler to parse in you head than `if !true` or `unless true`. Dealing with negations (or sometimes even double negations) makes you think twice. Therefore the community tries to avoid it.

But technically it is fine...

Answer (score 3):

It might be appropriate (more readable than any alternative) to use `unless ... else ...` when the code in the `else` block is very long and the code in the `unless` block is very short.

```
unless user.staff?
    raise SecurityError, 'not authorized'
else
    # ...
    # ...
    # ... lots of code
    # ...
    # ...
end
```

If you wrote this the other way around,

```
if user.staff?
    # ...
    # ...
    # ... lots of code
    # ...
    # ...
else
    raise SecurityError, 'not authorized'
end
```

the else-clause might be so far removed from its condition that you'd be making people scroll up and down to keep things straight in their heads.

*This particular example* is better written without an `else` at all...

```
unless user.staff?
    raise SecurityError, 'not authorized'
end

# ...
# ...
# ... lots of code
# ...
# ...
```

... but that transformation is not always possible.

Answer (score 0):

Executes code if conditional is false. If the conditional is true, code specified in the else clause is executed.

```
x=1
unless x>2
   puts "x is less than 2"
 else
  puts "x is greater than 2"
end
```

We can use else with unless but its a bad approach.